# Add InstNamer pass in llvm as a required pass

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, intermediate-language

I am performing an optimization in llvm that requires the InstNamer pass to be run before my optimization. Currently, I am running it by manually passing "-instnamer" to opt. Is there a way I can add InstNamer as a required pass in the code?

I tried doing
        AU.addRequired();

But that doesn't compile as it throws "undeclared identifier 'InstNamer'".

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the pass is decleared in include/llvm, then you can use `AU.addRequired<PassClassName>();`, which is actually `AU.addRequiredID(PassClassName::ID);`

If the pass is declared and defined in lib/, then you have to use `AU.addRequiredID(PassClassID);`

In this case, you have to use:

```
#include "llvm/Transforms/Scalar.h"

AU.addRequiredID(InstructionNamerID);
```